# grouping on ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, sorting, grouping, observablecollection

I'm in new in WPF, implementing application using mvvm pattern.
having below class

```
class student
{
  string name;
  int rollno;
}

In viewModel
public ObservableCollection<Student> Students{ get; private set; }
```

from above collection i want list of student and count whose name are same.

e.g.
student 
name : xyz, rollno : 1,
name : abc, rollno : 3,
name : xyz, zrollno : 2,
name : bc, rollno : 4,
name : abc, rollno : 5,

what i want is,

xyz, rollno 1
xyz, rollno 2

abc, rollno : 3
abc, rollno : 5

bc, rollno : 4

Comment: Did you try the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
  var result = students.GroupBy(n => n.Name).
                     Select(group =>
                         new
                         {
                             Name = group.Key,
                             RollNo = group.ToList()
                         });
```